# Estimating/translating odds ratio for different percentile intervals

Tags: logistic, quantiles, odds-ratio, odds

I have a question regarding a translation in odds ratio curve OR(x). More specifically, let's say we have an OR(x) which we get using logistic regression. We look at the interval bounded with 25% and 75% percentiles of the variable X and denote the value of interval with X<sub>25-75</sub>. For further interpretation of the odds ratio we want to have OR(X<sub>25-75</sub>) = 1, however in our case we get X<sub>50</sub> = 1.02. So my question is: how do we translate the odds ratio curve to get the OR(X<sub>25-75</sub>) = 1? In other words: How do we get the OR estimates for different percentile intervals?

See for example table 4 from [this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25855707) or table 2 from [this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/29892016).